# jquery hacer triger en cadena de alt+printpant luego volcar imagen en canvas

Tags: jquery, trigger

estoy tratando de crear un boton para reportes de errores:
y necesito mejorar el script del código para ejecutar las siguientes funciones:

1. handler del boton reportar error.
2. hacer trigger del combo alt+PrintScreen.
3. leer la imagen del clipboard.
4. convertir la imagen a string (base64).

Codigo javascript(Jquery):

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click",'[id^="button-test"]', function (event, xhr, settings) {
        console.log('event trigger');
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 44;       // # PrintScreen code value
        e.altKey = true;     // Alt key pressed
        $("input").trigger(e);

            retrieveImageFromClipboardAsBlob(e, function(imageBlob){
                if(imageBlob){
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function(){
                        canvas.width = this.width;
                        canvas.height = this.height;
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    };
                    var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    img.src = URLObj.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
                }
            });

    });
});
function retrieveImageFromClipboardAsBlob(pasteEvent, callback){
    if(pasteEvent.clipboardData == false){
        if(typeof(callback) == "function"){
            callback(undefined);
        }
    };
    var items = pasteEvent.clipboardData.items;
    if(items == undefined){
        if(typeof(callback) == "function"){
            callback(undefined);
        }
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        // Skip content if not image
        if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") == -1) continue;
        // Retrieve image on clipboard as blob
        var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
        if(typeof(callback) == "function"){
            callback(blob);
        }
    }
}
```

Código HTML:

```
<span>
    <button id="button-test">prueba</button>
</span>
<canvas style="border:1px solid grey;" id="mycanvas">
```

Errores:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

y se refiere a esta linea,

```
var items = pasteEvent.clipboardData.items;
```

no se que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes gatillar el combo `ALT + Print Screen` desde javascript, porque es un comando de sistema y JS está en un sandbox en donde todo lo que haces se circunscribe y limita al documento actual.

Imagínate que lo que estás proponiéndote se pudiera. Podrías gatillar el evento `CTRL + L` para bloquear la pantalla. ¿Sería un poco invasivo, no crees?

Lo que puedes hacer es valerte de librerías que convierten un objeto del DOM (o el DOM completo) en un canvas, como [HTML2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).